# UNIX 'ls' command exclude unwanted files

Tags: file, unix, ls

Current directory has below files.

```
hello.log
hello.2019-12-23.1.log
hello.2019-12-23.2.log
hello.2019-12-23.3.log
hello.log.2019-12-22.log.gz
hello.log.2019-12-21.log.gz
abc.log
xyz.log
```

I would like my **ls** command return only current log files (exclude all archive, old log files)

Below output is expected

```
hello.log
abc.log
xyz.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends greatly on the conditions of which one wants to ignore entries. Nonetheless, filename globbing expressions can be used to limit the results of the filename selection called with the `ls` command. The operations are not very sophisticated (unlike `regex`, for example), so only simple expressions can be used. In the example list of files in the original question, one could prune out only the desired files by only showing a specific extension (.e.g `.log)` that do not end with a number (e.g. `[!0-9]`)

So the `ls` command would look like this:

```
ls *[!0-9].log
```

This works for the example shown. However, it depends on the complexity of the filename list.